# Mac Word 2016 - How do I keep the changes of image size?

Tags: images, microsoft-word-2016

In Word 2016 on El Capitan, I've changed the size of many screenshot images, each different. I did this by selecting the image, right clicking, using the Size and Position option, and selecting a percentage of the original image. They look great. When I send the Word doc to a PC user, the images are different. For example, one that I had set for 100% showed up on her doc as 108%, which oversized text and picture of screenshot.

If the PC users put the doc onto Sharepoint, when I download it, the new, bad sizes of the images are all showing up on the Mac as well. Is there some way to tell Word to keep the images as they are? Obviously saving the doc before sending it out hasn't worked.